# Getting cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException despite adding Background in the feature file calc.feature

Tags: java, spring, selenium, cucumber, bdd

I am getting following error while running my `Cucumber` `Selenium` tests using `Spring Boot`

I have already added `Background` in the feature file. Not sure how to generalize the parameters that are getting passed in it.

Please guide.

**Error:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.example.TestRunner
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.388 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.TestRunner
initializationError(com.example.TestRunner)  Time elapsed: 0.004 sec  <<< ERROR!
cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException: Duplicate step definitions in com.example.stepdefs.GoogleCalcStepDefinition.I_enter_in_search_textbox(String) in file:/I:/pet-projects/junit-cucumber-demo/target/test-classes/ and com.example.stepdefs.GoogleCalcSte
pDefinition.I_enter_in_search_textbox2(String) in file:/I:/pet-projects/junit-cucumber-demo/target/test-classes/


Results :

Tests in error:
  TestRunner.initializationError » DuplicateStepDefinition Duplicate step defini...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[ERROR] There are test failures.
[INFO] About to generate Cucumber report.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.281 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-12T16:50:23-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**calc.feature**

```
Feature: Check addition in Google calculatorcontent
  In order to verify that Google calculator work correctly
  As a user of Google
  I should be able to get correct addition result

  Background: Do some arithmetic on Google
    Given I open Google

  Scenario: Addition
    When I enter "2+2" in search textbox
    Then I should get result as "4"

  Scenario: Multiplication
    When I enter "5*5" in search textbox
    Then I should get result as "25"
```

**GoogleCalcStepDefinition.java**

```
@Ignore
public class GoogleCalcStepDefinition extends DemoApplicationTests {

    WebDriver driver;
    GoogleSearchPage googleSearchPage;

    @Given("^I open Google$")
    public void I_open_google() {
        this.driver = BrowserConfig.getWebDriver();
        this.googleSearchPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, GoogleSearchPage.class);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in search textbox$")
    public void I_enter_in_search_textbox(String additionTerms) {
        googleSearchPage.searchBox.sendKeys(additionTerms); //passing 2+2 here
        googleSearchPage.searchBtn.click();
    }

    @Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_should_get_correct_result(String expectedResult) {
        String result = googleSearchPage.calculatorTextBox.getText();
        assertEquals(result, expectedResult); //Verify that result of 2+2 is 4
        BrowserConfig.releaseResources(driver);
    }

    @When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in search textbox$")
    public void I_enter_in_search_textbox2(String multiplicationTerms) {
        googleSearchPage.searchBox.sendKeys(multiplicationTerms); //passing 5*5 here
        googleSearchPage.searchBtn.click();
    }

    @Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_should_get_correct_result2(String expectedResult) {
        String result = googleSearchPage.calculatorTextBox.getText();
        assertEquals(result, expectedResult); //Verify that result of 5*5 is 25
        BrowserConfig.releaseResources(driver);
    }
}
```

**DemoApplicationTests.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public abstract class DemoApplicationTests {

}
```

**GoogleSearchPage.java**

public class GoogleSearchPage {

```
    @FindBy(name = "q")
    public WebElement searchBox;
    @FindBy(name = "btnK")
    public WebElement searchBtn;
    @FindBy(id = "cwos")
    public WebElement calculatorTextBox;

}
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json"},
        glue = {"com.example.stepdefs"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"})
public class TestRunner {

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two gherkin steps that are identical save for the numeric value, and the numeric value was parameterized out with Regex, leaving them completely identical.  So while the two steps in the gherkin are unique, the bindings in the step definition are duplicates:

```
@Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
```

and

```
@Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
```

Same for the two `When` steps.  You can either replace the Regex with the same hardcoded values as the gherkin (probably not what you want), or simply delete the duplicates since the steps look like they're properly handling the input argument.  Once the dups are deleted, the two steps in the gherkin will both map to the single remaining step def.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. I will post the updated answer below so that others can refer it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Bases on `@Nathaniel`'s response here is updated code base which help fixed the problem.

**calc.feature (no change required)**

**GoogleCalcStepDefinition .java**

```
@Ignore
public class GoogleCalcStepDefinition extends DemoApplicationTests {

    WebDriver driver;
    GoogleSearchPage googleSearchPage;

    @Given("^I open Google$")
    public void I_open_google() {
        this.driver = BrowserConfig.getWebDriver();
        this.googleSearchPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, GoogleSearchPage.class);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in search textbox$")
    public void I_enter_in_search_textbox(String input) {
        googleSearchPage.searchBox.sendKeys(input); //passing 2+2 and 5*5 here
        googleSearchPage.searchBtn.click();
    }

    @Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_should_get_correct_result(String expectedResult) {
        String result = googleSearchPage.calculatorTextBox.getText();
        assertEquals(result, expectedResult); //Verify that result of 2+2 is 4 and 5*5 is 25
        BrowserConfig.releaseResources(driver);
    }

}
```